# How to change the color of the a WPF `<Separator />`?

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors, separator

I use `<Separator />` in my form but don't know how to change its color. None of `Border` /`Foreground`/`Background` does exist. Plese help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use styles

```
    <Style x:Key="MySeparatorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Border 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        Height="1" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

A seperator is just a border element and now you can change its appearance any way you like?

Comment: It doesn't work with toolbar separators, check the answer from @code4life below.

Answer (score 78):

You can set the Background:

```
<Separator Background="Red"/>
```

Comment: Oh my god, that was unexpected. I thought Foreground should change the color of separator, not background

Answer (score 22):

Hmm... I think the `Separator` is one of the few elements that will not work using a simple style. Based on the MSDN documentation, you need to specify the `SeparatorStyleKey`.

For instance for a `ToolBar` you would do this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}" 
    TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="Background" 
        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Border 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    Height="1" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that works with a toolbar separator. None of the other answer works.

Comment: The key naming is important.

Comment: BTW, here is an article explaining why, and also mentioning how to style the other kind of separators, namely the MenuItem's separators: http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2008/06/19/styling-separators-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: This works too for menu items: x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}

Answer (score 13):

you can set the `Separator`'s color using this code:

`<Separator BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>`

NOTE that the `BorderThickness` property must be applied too.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by setting `BorderThickness="1 0 0 0"`. Otherwise, the separator was two pixels thick.

Comment: Orientation matters...horizonally, you want `BorderThickness="0 1 0 0"`.  Also, `UseLayoutRounding` might be necessary to avoid a fuzzy appearance.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you could choose to use a Rectangle element:

`<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue" Height="2"/>`

It's somewhat easier to modify/shape.

Comment: Is there a way to make the rectangle non-selectable in the contextmenu? The nice thing about the separator is you can't highlight it, it's not a real MenuItem child